# C++ strange performance with inherited class

Tags: c++, performance

As I understood things virtual function calls in a C++ class in an inheritance hierarchy should be a bit slower than the equivalent class that doesn't inherit from any base class, i.e. a self contained class.  I decided to write a small test program to see what the difference in performance was.

I have an inheritance hierarchy consisting of 3 classes: Shape, Rectangle, Quadrilateral.  I have one class called BaseQuadrilateral that doesn't inherit from anything, and does the same thing that the Quadrilateral class does.  There are two methods in each class: surfaceArea() and volume().  I am running a separate benchmark on each class and recording the time it takes to run with 10,000,000 objects.  I expected the Quadrilateral class would take slightly longer. Instead the Quadrilateral class (Inherited from Rectangle) runs and order of magnitude faster than BaseQuadrilateral.  I don't understand why this is.

```
Test Results:
Running Dynamic Dispatch Test

Quadrilateral Runtime: 2840264 Ticks, 2 Seconds.
BaseQuadrilateral Runtime: 21179219 Ticks, 21 Seconds.
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on behind the scenes that makes the inherited code so much faster and in what circumstances inherited code will run slower than non-inherited code.

Thank you

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual double surfaceArea() = 0;
    virtual double Volume() = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    //Constructors
    Rectangle();
    Rectangle(double, double);
    Rectangle(const Rectangle&);

    Rectangle& operator=(const Rectangle&);
    double Area();

    //Override Shape base class methods
    double surfaceArea();
    double Volume();
protected:
    double length;
    double width;
};

class Quadrilateral : public Rectangle
{
public:
    //Constructors
    Quadrilateral();
    Quadrilateral(double, double, double);
    Quadrilateral(const Quadrilateral&);

    Quadrilateral& operator=(const Quadrilateral&);

    //Overloaded Square base class
    double surfaceArea();
    double Volume();
protected:
    double height;
};

class BaseQuadrilateral
{
public:
    //Constructors
    BaseQuadrilateral();
    BaseQuadrilateral(double, double, double);
    BaseQuadrilateral(const BaseQuadrilateral&);

    BaseQuadrilateral& operator=(const BaseQuadrilateral&);
    double surfaceArea();
    double Volume();

protected:
    double length;
    double width;
    double height;
};

void test2()
{
    clock_t qTimer, bqTimer;
    Quadrilateral* quadrilaterals;
    BaseQuadrilateral* baseQuadrilaterals, baseQuadrilateral;
    Shape* shape;
    double* answers1, *answers2;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    cout << "Running Dynamic Dispatch Test\n" << endl;

    quadrilaterals = new Quadrilateral[ARRAY_SIZE];
    baseQuadrilaterals = new BaseQuadrilateral[ARRAY_SIZE];
    answers1 = new double[ARRAY_SIZE];
    answers2 = new double[ARRAY_SIZE];

    //Initialization
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        double length = (double)(rand() % 100);
        double width = (double)(rand() % 100);
        double height = (double)(rand() % 100);

        quadrilaterals[i] = Quadrilateral(length, width, height);
        baseQuadrilaterals[i] = BaseQuadrilateral(length, width, height);
    }

    //Test Shape
    qTimer = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        shape = &quadrilaterals[i];
        answers1[i] = shape->Volume();
    }

    qTimer = clock() - qTimer;

    //Test BaseQuadrilateral
    bqTimer = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        baseQuadrilateral = baseQuadrilaterals[i];
        answers2[i] = baseQuadrilateral.Volume();
    }

    bqTimer = clock() - qTimer;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (answers1[i] != answers2[i])
        {
            cout << "Incorrect answer found at i=" << i << ". answers1: " << answers1[i] << " answers2: " << answers2[i] << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    //Print Results
    cout << "Quadrilateral Runtime: " << qTimer << " Ticks, " << qTimer / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " Seconds." << endl;
    cout << "BaseQuadrilateral Runtime: " << bqTimer << " Ticks, " << bqTimer / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " Seconds." << endl;
}
```

Comment: This line might have a bit to do with it: `bqTimer = clock() - qTimer;`.  You appear to want that `qTimer` to be `bqTimer`.

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote in comments, you have a bit of an issue with this line:

```
bqTimer = clock() - qTimer;
```

. You appear to want that `qTimer` to be `bqTimer`.  That does not explain a difference as large as you observe, however.  For that, you should look carefully at your two test loops, and in particular at how they differ.

In the first case, you are recording a pointer to your `Quadrilateral` in variable `shape`, and then invoking the `Volume()` method indirectly through the pointer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    shape = &quadrilaterals[i];
    answers1[i] = shape->Volume();
}
```

In the second case, you are making a copy of the whole `BaseQuadrilateral` object, and then invoking the copy's `Volume()` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    baseQuadrilateral = baseQuadrilaterals[i];
    answers2[i] = baseQuadrilateral.Volume();
}
```

Copying an object is far more expensive than obtaining its address.  In this particular case, in fact, the address computation might even be optimized completely out.  I suggest avoiding the intermediary, and in both cases invoking the method directly on the array elements:

```
    answers1[i] = quadrilaterals[i].Volume();
```

or

```
    answers2[i] = baseQuadrilaterals[i].Volume();
```

Comment: Thanks John. I've corrected the timer issue.  Not sure how I missed that myself.  Once you pointed out that there was a copy going on with the `baseQuadrilateral` I realized that I didn't declare it is a pointer, which I intended to do, so that both loops would be equivalent.  Running the benchmark again gives about 2 seconds for `quadrilaterals` and 3-4 seconds for `baseQuadrilaterals`.  Same with your suggested lines of code as well.  That is a much more reasonable gap, but I still don't understand why `baseQuadrilateral` is slower than `quadrilateral`.  Why is it not the other way around?

Comment: After running the test a few more times, I will occasionally get `quadrilaterals` being slightly faster than `baseQuadrilaterals` by a few hundred thousand ticks, but most of the time `quadrilaterals` is coming in between 1-2 seconds and `baseQuadrilaterals` is coming in between 2-3 seconds.

Comment: @KelbyMadal, your test now tells you one thing for sure: the difference in performance between your two approaches is very small -- on the order of one microsecond per call at most for this case.  I can speak to why the measured performance compares differently than you expect, but I suspect inequivalent implementations of `Volume()` (which you have not presented).  There may also be any number of subtle differences in optimization or test implementation that affect the results.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help @JohnBollinger.  It may have something to do with optimization as you suspect.  Implementations of `Volume()` are the same for both classes except, of course, that one that is marked virtual in the `Shape` base class.


`double Quadrilateral::Volume()
{
    return length * width * height;
}`


`double BaseQuadrilateral::Volume()
{
    return length * width * height;
}`

Comment: Also, can you tell me how to add a line breaks between code blocks.  I'm new to stackoverflow and can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @KelbyMadal Putting an (unindented) HTML comment between code blocks should cause them to be formatted as separate blocks, but it's more natural to put a line or two of relevant text between blocks if it's in fact necessary to present them as separate blocks at all.

Answer (score 0):

Should this line

```
bqTimer = clock() - qTimer;
```

be

```
bqTimer = clock() - bqTimer;
```